# Vbscript Inputbox unselect the text

Tags: vba, vbscript

Below code works perfect but the inputbox show’s text as "Wind" with auto selecting in the inputbox.
Is there any option to show without selecting... I mean the cursor should be last character of "Wind"

mycode...

```
    Dim Prefex
    Prefex = "Wind"

   sNewComputerName = InputBox ("enter data here", "Computer Name", Prefex , 30,30)
    If sNewComputerName = "" then

    End If
```

Comment: Nope, that's what `InputBox()` does.

Comment: the issue with my code is it is selecting automatically

Comment: Yes, if you give the InputBox some default text, its always displayed selected.

Comment: is there any way not to select by default... please...

Comment: If you don't want the default text to be selected, do your own "InputBox" ;-)

Comment: The prefix value should be shown in the inputbox...

Comment: No, You cannot do that with InputBox()

Answer (score 1):

To summarize comments: 
InputBox is a very limited function, and doesn't have any possibility regarding the way it is selecting the default value.
so you need to press the right arrow before typing.
No other way around!

if you want nicer things, as @Rubik suggested, you can generate a proper InputBox with another language, you would be able to manage it. But that's a lot of work (rewrite your code!) for a minor disagreement!

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do?

A user can take Wind out of the box and it will not be returned.  If you want to make sure a user entered text the return value can be tested  for "" or Wind.

if you want the " displayed
chr(34) & "Wind" & chr(34)

If you just want to prefix everything with Wind I would do that after the text was retuned